# Rails create multiple records from comma delimited form param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having an issue creating multiple option_values from a form param field called "name" that has a value that looks like this: a1,a2,b2,c4. What I would like to do is create an option_value for each one of those entries but I'm not sure how to do it. I know that I need to split the value but I'm just not sure where to do that exactly.

Controller:

```
class Admin::OptionValuesController < Admin::ApplicationController
before_action :set_option_value, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /option_values
# GET /option_values.json
def index
  @option_values = OptionValue.all
end

# GET /option_values/1
# GET /option_values/1.json
def show
end

# GET /option_values/new
def new
  @option_value = OptionValue.new
end

# GET /option_values/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /option_values
# POST /option_values.json
def create
  @option_value = OptionValue.new(option_value_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @option_value.save
      format.html { redirect_to @option_value, notice: 'Option value was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @option_value }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @option_value.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /option_values/1
# PATCH/PUT /option_values/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @option_value.update(option_value_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @option_value, notice: 'Option value was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @option_value }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @option_value.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /option_values/1
# DELETE /option_values/1.json
def destroy
  @option_value.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to option_values_url, notice: 'Option value was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_option_value
    @option_value = OptionValue.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
  def option_value_params
    params.require(:option_value).permit(:option_type_id, :name)
  end
```

end

Form. Within the main product form this allows me to create an option_type and also at that time create multiple option_values which belong to the option_type: This is what I am doing.

[image: Sample Image]

```
<div class="grid md:grid-cols-1 row-gap-6 col-gap-4 lg:grid-cols-3 mb-4">
       <%= form.fields_for :option_types, OptionType.new do |options| %>
         <div>
           <%= options.label "Option Type Name", class: "text-gray-700" %>
           <%= options.text_field :name, class: 'w-full mt-2 px-4 py-2 block rounded bg-gray-200 text-gray-800 border border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:bg-white' %>
         </div>
         <div data-controller="nested-form">
           <%= options.fields_for :option_values, OptionValue.new do |ov| %>
             <%= render "admin/option_types/option_values_fields", form: ov %>
           <% end %>
         </div>

       <% end %>
     </div>
```

Models:

product:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
 has_many_attached :images, :dependent => :delete_all
 has_one_attached :main_image, :dependent => :delete_all
 has_many :product_option_types, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :product
 has_many :option_types
 has_many :option_values
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :option_types
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :option_values
 has_many :variants, inverse_of: :product, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Option_type

```
 class OptionType < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :option_values, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :option_values, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  has_many :product_option_types, dependent: :destroy
 end
```

option_value

```
  class OptionValue < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :option_type
   has_many :option_value_variants, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :variants, through: :option_value_variants
   validates_presence_of :name
   validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :option_type_id, case_sensitive: false

  def create_from_csv(comma_separated_string)
   comma_separated_string.split(',').map do |val|
    create(name: val)
   end
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method in your `OptionType` called `create_with_values`

In it you'd do something like

```rb
def self.create_with_values(type, names)
  type_instance = create(name: type)
  names.split(',').map do |val|
    type_instance.option_values.create(name: val)
  end
end
```

Instead of your `OptionValuesController`, your `OptionTypesController`'s create method should be

```rb
def create
  OptionType.create_with_values(type: params[:type], values: params[:name])
  redirect_to appropriate_path
end
```

A more railsy way to do this would be with nested attributes but you will have to setup your `create_with_values` method to transform the incoming comma separated strings into something that the nested attributes can accept.

Look at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html for more information

Comment: Thanks. I tried to put this together and get no errors but it still isn't splitting the field into multiple. And sorry I think I titled the thread incorrectly. I am not trying to create multiple records from a comma delimited list. I have a text_field that I input a value like this 1,2,3,4,5 and I want to split that form param and create multiple singular option_values from each of those values.

Comment: Your comment still makes me think you want to create individual values with 1 and with 2 and with 3 and so on. Can you update the question with what your params look like and what data you want created? That should make the question more clearer

Comment: I updated the post with some more info. Does that help?

Comment: Is the type and value both stored in the `OptionValue` model. Or is there a separate model for types? Can you post the relationships too?

Comment: Ok I see you have a separate model for OptionType. Instead of creating a new optionValue in the form, you can use a simple text field as an attr_accessor on the model, and create the values from the comma separated string. The controller you should be submitting your form to should be the OptionTypesController rather than the OptionValuesController since you're submitting type and creating values for the types which is the child association. I'm updating my answer to reflect the changes

Comment: Strange. It still doesn't seem to be splitting them. It is creating everything correctly just not separating them out.

Comment: Can you check if `names.split(',')` is actually returning an array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217418/discussion-between-spacerobot-and-moiz-mansur).